# Selecting a top row Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I made an asp  application which allows the user to search for records in the database. I altered that by allowing the user to search for only one row at each time he/she presses the search button. But my code to do this is not really working!
Class Products:

```
   public DataTable SelectRow()
   {
  string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Products ORDER BY ProductID ASEC";
  return SelectRow(sql);
   }
   public DataTable SelectRow(string Query)
   {
  try
  {
      return db.RunQuery(Query);
  }
  catch
  {
      return new DataTable();
  }
```

Button Search:

```
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        grid.DataSource = product.SelectRow();
        DataBind();
        lblMsg.Text = "";
        btnRemove.Enabled = false;
        btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
        grid.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
```

Please would you mind to alter my code to allow me search one record at a time. Thank you.

Comment: Why does your `SelectRow()` method return a Boolean? Shouldn't it return the actual row?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Loay Any response about returning `bool`?

Comment: @Loay Also, you say your code isn't working, but we need to know exactly what the code is doing in order to help you.

Comment: Right I made in DataTable but still not returning any!Have a look at the codes above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is not valid and your exception handling is swallowing the exception that would show you that.

There is no such thing as `ASEC` - is should simply be `ASC`:

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Products ORDER BY ProductID ASC";
```

Because you have a `try` **without** any sort of real consequence (a really bad practice), such as a rethrow or some logging, the actual exception is swallowed. You are running the catch block which returns an empty `DataTable`.

Don't do that. Get rid of that `try` block altogether - let the exception bubble up. If you had done that to begin with, you would have found out the problem almost immediately.

Don't use exception handling as a flow control mechanism - it is a bad practice.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you very for your contribution and I do appreciate it. You have a point about using try catch! I thought it is a good mechanism to catch up any exceptions if found. I agree with you when you mentioned it as a bad practice but it is a bit handy in some occasions.

Comment: @Loay - possibly. But a very rare occasion. By default, better to not do that.